# Why are my media queries not applying?

Tags: php, html, css, media-queries

**Edited to add**, so no one else posts this as an answer: I already have a viewport tag in my code.

---

I have read many of the responses here to similar questions, and I'm sure my problem probably lies somewhere in the order that my queries are declared in, but I can't for the life of me figure out where.

[Bootply example here.](http://www.bootply.com/GLeuQJC9xQ)

I have two divs, one that should display in wide layouts, and one that should display in narrow layouts.

```
<!-- for small layouts -->
<div class="container-fluid slogan text-center" id="home-slogan-container-small">
   small
</div>

<!-- for 800 px and wider -->
<div class="container-fluid slogan text-center" id="home-slogan-container-large">
   large
</div>
```

(These are very stripped-down; the actual content has different layouts inside the divs.)

The problem I'm having is that, no matter what size I scale the browser to (tested in FF using ctrl-shift-m to get mobile view, and in Chrome using the mobile view button in the dev tools), the small layout displays.

Here's my css:

```
#home-slogan-container-small {
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-align: center !important;
    display: none;
}

#home-slogan-container-large {
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-align: center !important;
    display: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
        #home-slogan-container-small { display: none !important;}
        #home-slogan-container-large { display: block !important;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #home-slogan-container-small { display: none !important;}
    #home-slogan-container-large { display: block !important;}
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    #home-slogan-container-small { display: none !important;}
    #home-slogan-container-large { display: block !important;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #home-slogan-container-small { display: block !important;}
    #home-slogan-container-large { display: none !important;}
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 799px) {
    #home-slogan-container-small { display: block !important;}
    #home-slogan-container-large { display: none !important;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    #home-slogan-container-small { display: block !important;}
    #home-slogan-container-large { display: none !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
    #home-slogan-container-small { display: block !important;}
    #home-slogan-container-large { display: none !important;}
}
```

I'm a PHP/mySQL developer who's had a bootstrap site dropped on me; CSS is not my strong suit. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to remove the last media query

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
   #home-slogan-container-small { display: block !important;}
   #home-slogan-container-large { display: none !important;}
}
```

the reason is, that this last is the only with min-width rule and overrule that all before (except in the case of wieport < 300px)

Comment: Thank you! Not sure how I missed that one.

Answer (score 3):

**Here's the problem**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
    #home-slogan-container-small { display: block !important;}
    #home-slogan-container-large { display: none !important;}
}
```

it's **min-width**... meaning anything with width greater than that (e.g. all browser) will have those properties be true.  Change it to max-width and you'll be fine.

---

Edit:  all of the below is true, but not the cause of @EmmyS problem.  Solution is above.

I recently had this issue with Foundation, and I suspect bootstrap has the issue too.  your html is *probably* missing a meta declaration:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

add that into the head of your HTML and it will probably work fine.  The reason you're having this problem is because the mobile browser is deciding "okay, I don't know how to display this website, so I'm going to scale it as if I was a large browser, even though I'm not."

Comment: Nope, it's just the opposite - it's scaling it as if it's a small browser, even if it's not.  And I do have the viewport tag in my html.

Comment: Right you are.  Edited my answer to have your root cause... I read your question too fast!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite all styling like this:

```
/* Styles for size 0px - 799px */
.small {
  display: block;
}

.middle {
  display: none;
}

.large {
  display: none;
}

/* Styles for size 800px - 1200px */
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .small {
    display: none;
  }

  .middle {
    display: block;
  }

  .large {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* Styles for size 1200px and more */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .small {
    display: none;
  }

  .middle {
    display: none;
  }

  .large {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I choosed 800px and 1200px as the breakpoints. You can modify them or add new ones.